# INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp

Ao submeter um formulário, eu estava testando a quantidade de informação que posso enviar via HTTP. Estou utilizando SGBD Mysql. Tenho uma aplicação que executa vários campos do tipo textarea.

Exemplo: um formulário com 10 textarea (utilizo um limitador de campo para validar à quantidade de caractere digitado). Para cada textarea permito o usuário digitar até 400 caracteres.

A pergunta é: existe alguma forma do Mysql aceitar mais valores? Existe alguma configuração, que deve ser feita? Exemplo: cada textarea aceitar 2000 caractere! Segue informação gerada no console:

```
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

Comment: Consegue nos mostrar o código? Parece que o problema não é o MySQL, mas a forma de como está submetendo as informações do formulário para o servidor.

Comment: Dherik, estava lendo sobre MYSQL, e segundo a documentação, o Banco de Dados, só aceita até 8000 Bytes. Dai tive que calcular a quantidade de caractere a ser submetido e ou dividir para salvar em 2 ou mas tabela. Muito obrigado! Abraços.